# Partial derivative w.r.t an integration

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

For example, I have a functional 
$$J(f)=\int \frac{f(x)}{1+x^2}dx.$$
How to calculate $\frac{\partial J}{\partial f(x)}$? Does it equal to $\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$? It seems that the question is somewhat confusing, but I really do not know how to express it.

Comment: Since the functional is linear, its derivative is itself.

Comment: Could you please explain more?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit confusing because there are many "directions" you can differentiate in. If $\phi$ is a compactly supported smooth function, then you can define the directional derivative 
$$J_\phi(f) = \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}J(f + t\phi) = \int \phi(x)\bigg( \frac{1}{1+x^2}\bigg)dx$$
I would interpret this in a distributional sense: the derivative $\frac{\partial J}{\partial f(x)}$ is not the *number* $\int\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$ but the *functional*
$$\phi \mapsto \int \phi(x) \bigg(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\bigg)dx.$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think the derivative is just $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ as shown in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative

Comment: @MIMIGA The derivative is $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ *understood as a distribution*, that is, the linear functional $\phi\mapsto \int \frac{\phi}{1+x^2}$.